# NSDateFormatter returning nil with dateFromString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using the following code to change yyyy-MM-dd to M-dd-yyyy using NSDateFormatter but NSLog is returning the value nil. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
NSString *trimmedDOB=@"1992-11-15";
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[format setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSDate *DateOfBirth=[format dateFromString:trimmedDOB];

NSLog(@"DATE IS %@",DateOfBirth);
```

Comment: Ask yourself:  Does your format string at all resemble the format of the date you're trying to convert??

Comment: Form a date first and then change its `dateFormat`. Set the date format of your original string. Form date using `NSDateFormatter` using its format. Change the format of the formatter and convert.

Comment: I am trying to convert yyyy-MM-dd to MM-dd-yyyy. Please tell me that where I am committing mistake.

Comment: dateFromString method converts String to Date. @Anupdas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *trimmedDOB=@"1992-11-15";
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//Set your input format
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

//Parse date from input format
NSDate *dateOfBirth = [format dateFromString:trimmedDOB];

//Set your output format
[format setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

//Output date in output format
NSLog(@"DATE IS %@",[format stringFromDate:dateOfBirth]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below:

```
NSString *trimmedDOB=@"1992-11-15";
NSDateFormatter *inFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *DateOfBirth=[inFormat dateFromString:trimmedDOB];
NSDateFormatter *outFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSLog(@"DATE IS %@", [outFormat stringFromDate:DateOfBirth]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *trimmedDOB=@"1992-11-15";
NSDateFormatter *dateformatterIn = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatterIn setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *DateOfBirth=[dateformatterIn dateFromString:trimmedDOB];
NSDateFormatter *dateformatterOut = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatterOut setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Each date format corresponds to a single date format. 
Since you have 2 date formats (one date string you are converting from and the one you are converting to) you need two date formatters.

So to convert from one date string to the other :

1. Create 'from' date formatter (format: yyyy-MM-dd)
2. Convert your source 'date string' into an 'NSDate object'
3. Create 'to' date formatter (format: MM-dd-yyyy)
4. Convert the 'NSDate object' you created in step 2 into the final 'date string'